# Purging checkpoint data from spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way I can purge older checkpoint data written by Java Spark streaming application? As the application runs for longer period, the checkpoint director grows really huge.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Spark Version 1.6

```
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
```

This was available from Spark 1.4

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2033

Also if you are still using DStreams , there is a `cleanup` method which deletes the checkpoint files that are older than the oldest batch for the input time

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStreamCheckpointData.scala

Comment: I am using spark 2.2 and Dataset. Does clearing the checkpoints happen by default? I am trying to find similar property for Spark 2.2

Comment: No ,you have to set it explicitly like this.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleanerSuite.scala#L51

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. After I set it as true, I have started getting errors like "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file */state/0/1/1.delta does not exist". I think it is expecting some checkpoint files which is not there anymore. But the job fails quite immediately after starting.

Comment: I am not sure why exactly this is happening. But can you please try setting,
 .set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking", "true")
 .set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking.shuffle", "true")
 .set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")